# ChartJS: Change the positions of the tooltips

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have a problem with ChartJS: I need to use a Polar graph for my project and I have to show this graphic in a PDF.

I also need to display the tooltips without hover. The problem is that these tooltips are at the center of each data.
I want this specific one to be found outside of the graph. I modified the Chart.js a lot and now I have:
[image: tooltips]

Unfortunately when the labels are long, the display is not good:
[image: Long labels]

My method is not good. Has someone already managed to display tooltips outside the circle?

Comment: How would you  like your chart to look like when there are long labels? (there are a few options - you could rotate the text outward, align the labels (left or right end to the edge of the outermost circle...)

Answer (score 5):

Currently the *center* of your label text is at the position where you want to show the label. If you change it to the start of your label or end of your label for labels on the right and left of your chart, you'll have much better layout.

You could also align your labels closer to the sector end point instead of the outermost edge of the scale.

Here's how you do it

**1. Override your scale**

So that the chart does not take up the full canvas. I've hardcoded these values for a sample dataset, you could just as easily use the input data to get suitable values

```
scaleOverride: true,
scaleStartValue: 0,
scaleStepWidth: 40,
scaleSteps: 10,
```

**2. Draw your Labels**

The best place would be the end of your animation.

```
onAnimationComplete: function () {
    this.segments.forEach(function (segment) {
```

Figure out the outer edge of each sector - this is not that difficult. We just use the same function that the tooltip position uses

```
var outerEdge = Chart.Arc.prototype.tooltipPosition.apply({
    x: this.chart.width / 2,
    y: this.chart.height / 2,
    startAngle: segment.startAngle,
    endAngle: segment.endAngle,
    outerRadius: segment.outerRadius * 2 + 10,
    innerRadius: 0
})
```

outerRadius decides how far away from the center you want your labels to appear. The x 2 is because the tooltip normally appears in the middle of the sector. The + 10 is padding so that the label does not stick too close to end of the sector

If you want the labels to all appear on the outer edge of the scale use `outerRadius = self.scale.drawingArea * 2` (*with self set to the Chartjs chart object*)

**3. Set the text alignment**

This is based on whether you are on the right or left side of the graph (or the top or bottom).

For this, first normalize the angle (so that it is within 0 to 2 * PI)

```
var normalizedAngle = (segment.startAngle + segment.endAngle) / 2;
while (normalizedAngle > 2 * Math.PI) {
    normalizedAngle -= (2 * Math.PI)
}
```

Then simply set the text position depending on the range of the angle (0 radians is on the right side middle and the radians increase anticlockwise).

```
if (normalizedAngle < (Math.PI * 0.4) || (normalizedAngle > Math.PI * 1.5))
    ctx.textAlign = "start";
else if (normalizedAngle > (Math.PI * 0.4) && (normalizedAngle < Math.PI * 0.6)) {
    outerEdge.y += 5;
    ctx.textAlign = "center";
}
else if (normalizedAngle > (Math.PI * 1.4) && (normalizedAngle < Math.PI * 1.6)) {
    outerEdge.y -5;
    ctx.textAlign = "center";
}
else
    ctx.textAlign = "end";
```

The "center" makes labels that appear near the top and bottom of the graph have the *middle* of their text align to the sector edge. The +5 and -5 are padding so that they don't stick too close.

```
ctx.fillText(segment.label, outerEdge.x, outerEdge.y);
```

---

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/nyjodx4v/

---

And here's how it looks

[image]