# Chart.js always visible labels

Tags: javascript, angularjs, charts, chart.js

I'm reworking a application for a client, and they want to show a chart. They currently use a infragistics chart, and they would love to stop using that, but the layout must remain the same.

this is the layout they want( so labels should be visible, individual bars, ...) 
[image: chart]

So my first option was to try out Chart.js, but I could only get something like this:

[image: Chart2]

So basicly the only thing that needs to happen is a way to always show the labels.

The data is provided via angular and is just an array if integers. Using the following directive for the chart: http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/

My current html:

```
<canvas id="polar" class="chart chart-polar-area" data="data.values" labels="data.labels" width="200" height="200"
        options="{animateRotate: false}"></canvas>
```

I found this; [How to add label in chart.js for pie chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22524295/how-to-add-label-in-chart-js-for-pie-chart) but I couldn't get it to work

Comment: See:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25661197/chart-js-doughnut-show-tooltips-always
or
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31783587/char-js-how-to-show-labels-by-default-in-pie-chart

Comment: @Sabba first is the one I provided in the question, second gonna look into it

Comment: Looked into the second one, that's not how they want it, they want it like the first one, so labels should be on the border of the bars. and when the value = 0 it should still show the label

Comment: @Kiwi - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31209359/chartjs-change-the-positions-of-the-tooltips/31221515#31221515 seems close to what you want.

Comment: @potatopeelings yep that seems indeed close, but now I only need to get it to work with the angular-chart version

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on [ChartJS: Change the positions of the tooltips](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31209359/chartjs-change-the-positions-of-the-tooltips/31221515#31221515)

---

**Preview**

[image]

---

Converting the above to angular-chart is easy because we are only setting the options. However we need to make 2 minor changes (i.e. set chart and ctx variables from `this`

```
// THIS IS REQUIRED AND WAS ADDED
tooltipEvents: [],
onAnimationComplete: function () {
    // THESE 2 LINES ARE NEW
    var chart = this.chart;
    var ctx = this.chart.ctx;

    this.segments.forEach(function (segment) {
        var outerEdge = Chart.Arc.prototype.tooltipPosition.apply({
            // THESE 2 LINES WERE CHANGED
            x: chart.width / 2,
            y: chart.height / 2,
            startAngle: segment.startAngle,
            endAngle: segment.endAngle,
            outerRadius: segment.outerRadius * 2 + 10,
            innerRadius: 0
        })
    ...
```

---

The entire code assuming you have the library scripts included looks something like this

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="myController">
        <canvas id="polar-area" class="chart chart-polar-area" data="data" labels="labels" options="options"></canvas>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Script**

```
angular.module('myApp', ["chart.js"]);
angular.module('myApp').controller('myController', function ($scope) {
        $scope.labels = ["Download Sales", "In-Store Sales", "Mail-Order Sales", "Tele Sales", "Corporate Sales"];
        $scope.data = [300, 500, 100, 40, 120];
        $scope.options = {
            scaleOverride: true,
            scaleStartValue: 0,
            scaleStepWidth: 40,
            scaleSteps: 10,
            tooltipEvents: [],
            onAnimationComplete: function () {
                var chart = this.chart;
                var ctx = this.chart.ctx;

                this.segments.forEach(function (segment) {
                    var outerEdge = Chart.Arc.prototype.tooltipPosition.apply({
                        x: chart.width / 2,
                        y: chart.height / 2,
                        startAngle: segment.startAngle,
                        endAngle: segment.endAngle,
                        outerRadius: segment.outerRadius * 2 + 10,
                        innerRadius: 0
                    })

                    var normalizedAngle = (segment.startAngle + segment.endAngle) / 2;
                    while (normalizedAngle > 2 * Math.PI) {
                        normalizedAngle -= (2 * Math.PI)
                    }

                    if (normalizedAngle < (Math.PI * 0.4) || (normalizedAngle > Math.PI * 1.5))
                        ctx.textAlign = "start";
                    else if (normalizedAngle > (Math.PI * 0.4) && (normalizedAngle < Math.PI * 0.6)) {
                        outerEdge.y += 5;
                        ctx.textAlign = "center";
                    }
                    else if (normalizedAngle > (Math.PI * 1.4) && (normalizedAngle < Math.PI * 1.6)) {
                        outerEdge.y - 5;
                        ctx.textAlign = "center";
                    }
                    else
                        ctx.textAlign = "end";

                    ctx.fillText(segment.label, outerEdge.x, outerEdge.y);
                })
            }
        }
    }
);
```

---

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/tmzpy7Lt/

Comment: Wow nice! one small question, is it possible to remain the labels? because when I hover it, they dissapear

Comment: @Kiwi - oops. I missed setting the tooltipEvents. Have updated the answer and the fiddle.

Comment: nice! am I now trying to get a segment line, and also trying to figure out that it won't cut off the top label, currently I have this; https://jsfiddle.net/etLrhukn/2/

Comment: One hacky way would be to increase the scales steps by 1 and reduce the outerRadius a bit. https://jsfiddle.net/mnqLzp7y/. For the segments, I guess you could (mis)use the tooltipPosition function again with the startAngle and endAngle reduced / increased by half the angle between them to get the edges of each sector and then draw the lines using ctx.

Comment: yea i'm doing the (mis)use, and take a look a this if you can, I've added some width and height to the canvas and the following happens: https://jsfiddle.net/mnqLzp7y/1/

Comment: Sorry forgot to add the /1/ to my jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mnqLzp7y/1/ addwf the widht and height ;)

Comment: Er... don't see any radial lines in that. Checked my last fiddle? (https://jsfiddle.net/qvheguL2/). Btw, with the original tooltip position you could also draw those little bubbles on the edge of each sector.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85102/discussion-between-kiwi-and-potatopeelings).